# Provide a link in an sql query based on ID

Tags: php, sql

So I'm having trouble figuring out how to show a link to a new page based on ID. I've created a review page of all timecards submitted based on employee. It works fine, but in case the employee wants to review an individual record and change specific things in the record is where i'm having trouble with. Below is a snippit of code i'm using to display the information. Because the timecard has MANY fields in I don't need to waste the whole page showing all the information until the employee actually submits the specific card he wants.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID,employee,date FROM tcardsubmit WHERE employee = '$empname");

 echo "<table border='1'>
 <tr>
 <th>ID</th>
 <th>EMPLOYEE NAME</th>
  <th>DATE</th>
 </tr>";

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['employee'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   }
 echo "</table>";
```

That query shows all I really need the employee to see. What i'd like is for the ID number to carry over to a page called 'review.php' but the ID number carries over with it, then I can just use GET ID and pull all the data based on the ID on the review page. Any suggestions?

Comment: Like this: `echo "<td><a href='review.php?ID=" . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $row['ID'] . "</a></td>";` and then in `review.php` you do `$ID = $_GET['ID']`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: TRUTH- TY for the tutorial. I wasn't aware MySQL was an issue at all to be honest. I'm only just learning on my own for the last month or two. Just based on tutorials on the web. I'll read up and PDO and try that out. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a little change on your table

```
 echo "<table border='1'>
 <tr>
 <th>ID</th>
 <th>EMPLOYEE NAME</th>
 <th>DATE</th>
 <th>ACTION</th>
 </tr>";

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['employee'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td><a href=review.php?ID=" . $row['ID'] . ">Review</a></td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   }
 echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks!! I like your way of displaying the "REVIEW" section in the code. Makes much better sense doing it that way. Then they wont be confused by clicking on an ID number! You made it simple!

Comment: in the future you can also change the review text to be an image,, just replace the text "Review" inside that link with <img src="review.png" title="Review" alt="Review" width="24" height="24" />

Answer (score 1):

In the loop add another column and do

```
echo '<td><a href="review.php?id=' .  $row['ID'] . '">View</a></td>';
```

In review.php

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
```

And query..

```
SELECT <fields> FROM tcardsubmit WHERE ID = $id
```

Make sure to escape id .. I did it by casting to an int, but you can also do mysql_real_escape_string